# Call a "document.pressed" action from the URL bar

Tags: javascript, html, url

In my legacy website, I found this

```
<input type="image" id="QuickPass" name="QuickPass"  src="/images/QuickPass.gif"  alt="Quick Pass" onclick="document.pressed=this.value" value="QuickPass" />
```

inside of this form

```
<form name="ListForm" method="post" onSubmit="return OnSubmitForm();" accept-charset="UTF-8" >
```

There is a JavaScript method to catch the `OnSubmitForm()` method

```
function OnSubmitForm(cbLength) {
//Snip
    else if (document.pressed == 'QuickPass'){
        //Do stuff
        return true;
    }
//Snip
}
```

Is there a way to trigger the submit via the for the `QuickPass` through the URL bar?  I though that `javascript:(document.getElementById("QuickPass").onclick())` would work but it just returns "undefined" (in the Chrome consol) and does nothing in IE6 (where it was built to run)

Notes: I did not write the original code but I am maintaining it.  Also, I cannot re-write the code to make it more URL-bar-friendly because we are at the end of a dev cycle and today is my last day on the project.  Finally, the code works quite well as-is when the buttons are physically clicked (and has for 5 years).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling an .onClick() method instead of a .click()
Try

```
javascript:(document.getElementById("QuickPass").click())
```